# ¿Cuál es la historia de las 2 palabras para los puntos cardinales oriente/este y occidente/oeste?

Tags: etimología, sinónimos, geografía

En español el punto cardinal **oriente** también se le llama **este** y el punto cardinal **occidente** también se le llama **oeste**.

En el Diccionario de la Real Academia, si se busca **oriente** lo remite a la palabra **este** y si se busca **occidente** lo remite a la palabra **oeste**.

La pregunta es ¿cuál es la historia u origen para que esos 2 puntos cardinales tengan 2 palabras?

Comment: No sé porque se cambiaron los nombres a los actuales de origen germánico pero no solo el *este* y el *oeste* tienen otros nombres, el *norte* y el *sur* tambien: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_cardinal

Comment: The English Wikipedia has more details about etymology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction#Germanic_origin_of_names although it is a little vague about the exact history.

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta rápida desde el móvil:

Los vocablos este y oeste nos vienen del francés *est* y *ouest* respectivamente, al igual que otros términos marítimos como estribor de *(es)tribord* y babor de *babord*.
Por otra parte, oriente y occidente vienen del latín: *oriens, orientis* significando más o menos "lugar por donde nace (el sol)", *occidens, occidentis* "lugar por donde cae".

En literatura y documentos formales lo normal era usar el derivado latino, pero en comercio lo normal era usar los términos marinos. Ninguno de los dos desplazó al otro y por eso hoy tenemos dos.